# Viewing revision history of form.cs or other multi-part items

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn, version-control

We have a .NET windows form project. A form consists of three files: Form.cs Form.Designer.cs and Form.resx. I am trying to view the revision history of Form.cs from Visual Studio using SVN. However, it open all three files, and doesn't let me to view the history/changes of just Form.cs. I am able to view changes for Form.Designer.cs and Form.resx. 
The same issue also happens for other multipart files such as app.config / debug.config, etc... family.
Is there a way to view revision changes for the top level item/ file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to do it: (subversion specific)
Right click on the top level item > Subversion > Compare.
This dialog allows you to pick and choose a specific file, and revision.